# How to solve this error, HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL?

Tags: servlets, http-post

I have below code:

When I run in Apache tomcat server it gives me this error:

> HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

Below I mention one admin.html file which I am calling.

It's have post method, and calling [MoviesServlet.java] which have override doPost(). //(I also try in other workspace.)

admin.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="fs" method="post">
        <h1>Released Movie</h1>

    </form>
</body>
```

MovieServlet.java

```
public class MovieServlet extends HttpServlet{

    private SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
```

web.xml

```
<display-name>hib_servlet_getUpdate</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>admin.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MovieServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/fs</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MovieServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.jspiders.getUpdateApp.Servlet.MovieServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
```

Comment: Please past full servlet source code

Comment: Do you run servlet or html page?

Comment: admin.html, I gave it in welcome file... so it run admin.html, but ar post it's giving error.

Comment: How do you post? There no submit button or etc for posting. Please post full source for better answer

Comment: i post full code...

Answer (score 0):

Its seems that your MovieServlet.java not shown all, but let me help you if you are using

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("index_F.html");
view.forward(request, response);
```

Do this

```
response.sendRedirect("index.html");
return;
```

I wish that this could help you solve the problem.